# Trying to install ionic globally error on MacbookPro

Tags: macos, ionic-framework, npm, global

[image]

When launch the command npm install @ionic/cli-framework -g
I have a error 404
Anyone can help me?

thanks

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or using a custom npm registry? If not, do you get an output running `npm info @ionic/cli-framework time`?

Comment: I can't paste all the info because stackoverflow block me this is a part'1.0.3': '2018-08-06T20:53:44.389Z',
  '1.0.4': '2018-08-07T04:15:30.508Z',
  '1.1.0-testing.6a88cfe2': '2018-08-08T22:33:23.705Z',
  '1.0.5': '2018-08-09T16:04:51.808Z',
  '1.0.6': '2018-08-20T21:21:57.863Z',
  '1.0.7': '2018-09-05T00:39:39.553Z'

Comment: Thanks for that :) any chance you could paste the output of `npm install @ionic/cli-framework -g --verbose` into Pastebin or an alternative? You could also try clearing the npm cache in the meantime by executing `npm cache clean -f`.

Comment: In addition to the above, when you say that you're installing Ionic globally, do you mean as per the [documentation](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/installation/cli)? In which case, I think the command should read `npm install -g ionic` rather than `@ionic/cli-framework`.

Comment: nothing work properly, this il verbose:
npm verb cwd /Users/varp/Workspaces/Pako/show-time
npm verb Darwin 18.0.0
npm verb argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "@ionic/cli-framework" "-g" "--verbose"
npm verb node v8.11.3
npm verb npm  v6.4.1
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @ionic/cli-framework@latest
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]
npm timing npm Completed in 1628ms

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/varp/.npm/_logs/2018-09-27T19_03_59_349Z-debug.log

Comment: I would suggest if you're just trying to install Ionic globally to use the command `sudo npm install -g ionic` as per the docs in that case. Let me know if that fails, happy to help further :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no package called `@ionic/cli-framework`. It's not the valid CLI from the ionic team. The correct command is to run

```
npm install -g ionic
```

If you're facing permissions issues, you may need to run that with `sudo`

```
sudo npm install -g ionic
```

[Ionic Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/installation/#ionic-cli-and-cordova)

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo npm install -g ionic` if your are running on a Mac or Linux machine.